# how to integrate my custom created phonegap plugin from xcode in my dot net project

Tags: xcode, cordova, devextreme

I am developing a hybrid mobile application in dot net, i have created my own custom plugin using x_code and phone_gap . what are the ways to integrate my plugin to dot_net project.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, but maybe this answer can help someone down the road.

This is the approach I have taken with DevExtreme to use a custom plugin and at the same time use the PhoneGap build process.

1. Upload your plugin to your GitHub Account.
2. Update your Config.xml

<gap:plugin name="your git hub package url" source="git"/>

(instead of name="" use spec="" and source="git")

NOTE: as of this post there is a bug in DevExtreme that if you attempt to look at Project Properties > PhoneGap Tab Studio will crash. DX is aware and they are suppose to fix it.

3. Build a custom template (this is the PhoneGap build portion)
4. Build your project.